# Two similar friendly urls - how to differentiate

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am facing issues with two similar friendly urls. I have mentioned the following lines in htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) /sitename/profile.php?id_profile=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/articles /sitename/articles.php?id_profile=$1 [QSA,N]
```

When I try to access the second url, it redirects back to the first url. I guess the very first part 'user' is causing this issue.

Here id_profile is a string. In the php file, i fetch the corresponding user id (integer) for id_profile and perform the rest of the action.

Here is a similar working example.
https://www.etsy.com/people/vinubhai
https://www.etsy.com/people/vinubhai/favorites

I want to make it work like the etsy one. Please do help.

Thanks and Regards,
Vineshkumar Kunhiraman

Comment: put the links in two separate `$vars`, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first rule gets processed first. chang the order of your rules and your problem should be solved.

first the articles rewrite, then the user general rewrite.

Comment: Thanks Galen and Michael Dibbets, it is working now by reversing the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `$` to anchor the end of the string or you can switch the order

```
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$
```

This wont match the articles url

Switching the order will cause the articles to match first, while the profile url will not match the article rewrite rule